# CSS Margin Issue - Unable to get a space between <section> and <header>

Tags: css

My code is up here : https://jsfiddle.net/krbomcj5/
It's small and self explanatory for a CSS pro. 
What's the issue is, I'm expecting a space between the `.main-content` and `.head-content`.
I'm able to achieve it by adding a padding to `.main-content`.

What is the alternate best practice if I want to get a space between `.main-content` and `.head-content`

Comment: Why not add padding to `.main-content`? Seems to me as the correct way.

Comment: I want to achieve it by modifying .head-content and not .main-content

Comment: You could add `overflow: auto;` to `.main-content`. It then will regard the margin of the child, though youre technically still modyfing the main-content. plus it adds scrollbars if the content is overflowing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `display: block; overflow: hidden` to the `.main-content`

```
.main-content {
  background-color: #28AFB0;
  width: 99%;
  height : 1000px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
  display: block; overflow: hidden;}


.head-content {
  background-color: #1F271B;
  height: 90px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 150px auto; }
```

Here is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/shihab_codepen/pen/NMEPKq)

Comment: That fixes it. Thanks!

Comment: @MaccenWright no need display:block, a section is by default a block element

Answer (score 0):

set `display: inline-block;` to head

```css
.main-content {
  background-color: #28AFB0;
  width: 99%;
  height : 1000px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

.head-content {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #1F271B;
  height: 90px;
  width: 95%;
  margin: 10px auto;

}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="main-content">
    <header class="head-content">

    </header>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: You didn't get the question I guess. I need spacing between the top of .head-content and the orange box.

Comment: fine i will edit and explain better your question i can not guess what you mean when you write space without spesific

Comment: see my edit please

Answer (score 0):

Padding is the way to go. You can also use the `top` property which requires some tweaks.

Setting `display: block` for `header` solves the issue in your example.

A good tutorial regarding layouts with css: http://learnlayout.com/.